# iPhone crash log appears to have crashed in [UIApplication run]

Tags: iphone, crash, crash-reports

I just downloaded the crash logs for my app from iTunes connect and there are 6 of the same crashes that I do not understand.  Here is what I think is the important part of the log (let me know if there is another part I should be looking at):

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0007e98c __kill + 8
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0007e97c kill + 4
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0007e96e raise + 10
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0009361a abort + 34
4   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x000453b0 __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler() + 376
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00005858 _objc_terminate + 104
6   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x00043776 __cxxabiv1::__terminate(void (*)()) + 46
7   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x000437ca std::terminate() + 10
8   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x00043896 __cxa_throw + 74
9   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00004714 objc_exception_throw + 64
10  Foundation                      0x000013c2 __NSThreadPerformPerform + 570
11  CoreFoundation                  0x00056620 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 692
12  CoreFoundation                  0x00056356 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 42
13  GraphicsServices                0x00003b2c GSEventRunModal + 108
14  GraphicsServices                0x00003bd8 GSEventRun + 56
15  UIKit                           0x00002768 -[UIApplication _run] + 384
16  UIKit                           0x0000146c UIApplicationMain + 688
17  ------                          0x000023ac main (main.m:6)
18  ------                          0x00002348 start + 44
```

As far as I can tell my code is never even called (aside from main which was autogenerated by xcode) so how should I go about figuring out what the cause of this crash is.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade xcode and your iPhone SDK to the latest version.  Without source code I can only think that the issue was caused by a "dead" NSThread, or your app received a kill message because it was using too much memory or some other cause.

Comment: Too high memory usage or not responding in time has the header: 0x8badf00d (a silly joke of some programmer in the watchdog team)